# How to add custom data to loaded Magento collection

Tags: php, magento

I've been working on merging two different collections together and I'm finding it very hard to do.

Actually, the only thing I'm trying to do is adding another property to an already instantiated (I think) collection.

This is my code:

```
private function _addProductsToBanners()
{
    $skus = $this->_getBannersSkus();

    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('in' => $skus))
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'));

    /** @var Developer_Banners_Model_Resource_Banner_Collection $banners */
    $banners = $this->banners;

    foreach ($banners as $banner) {
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if ($banner->getSku() == $product->getSku())
            {
                $banner->setData('product', 1);
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($banners->getData());
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

The problem here is, that when printing the `$banners` collection with `getData()` I can't see the `[product]` property, but if I do it without `getData()` then I see it.

If you have any ideas I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Developer_Banners_Model_Resource_Banner_Collection` inherits from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` and you add an item, the item is not added to the $_data property but to the $_items property.

```
protected function _addItem($item)
{
   $this->_items[] = $item;
   return $this;
}
```

When you call then the `getData()` method, the $_data property is still null. The getData() method will then fetch the data from the DB and return the result.

```
public function getData()
{
    if ($this->_data === null) {


        $this->_renderFilters()
             ->_renderOrders()
             ->_renderLimit();
        /**
         * Prepare select for execute
         * @var string $query
         */
        $query       = $this->_prepareSelect($this->getSelect());
        $this->_data = $this->_fetchAll($query, $this->_bindParams);
        $this->_afterLoadData();
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

By just iterating on the object the `each()` method is executed:

```
public function each($obj_method, $args=array())
    {
        foreach ($args->_items as $k => $item) {
            $args->_items[$k] = call_user_func($obj_method, $item);
        }
    }
```

This method uses the `$_items` property as data source. 
Unfortunately I can't explain this behaviour right now.

Comment: Thanks! When you'll have time - can you explain why isn't the _data property used for on the collection, since it'll end up being filled by the same data as the _items originally were?

Comment: I will try to add an explanation later.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I found out is that the collection `_data` property is not being set until you actually call `getData()`, but the `_data` on each collection member is actually set, so it's possible to access the newly added property when iterating the collection.